# Google plus share link invalid & FB Social Share fails

Tags: google-plus, share, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-share, socialshare

When I try to share my webpage on google plus it shows as link is invalid. Also for FB share it shows as 404 not found. While on FB Share debugger the URL crawls correct.

```
<a class="jssocials-share-link" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fofficial-store%3Futm_campaign%3Dcampaign_name%26utm_medium%3Dshare_button%26utm_source%3Dgoogleplus" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.example.com%2Ftext1-text2%3Futm_campaign%3Dcampaign_name%26utm_medium%3Dshare_button%26utm_source%3Dgoogleplus','_blank','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=800, height=600');"><i class="icon-google-plus white jssocials-share-logo"></i></a>
```

Please suggest what can be the problem. I have followed https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/ , cant find any information regarding this.

Comment: Make sure the URL you are trying to share is public on the internet.

Comment: The URL is public. But it still shows as invalid.
The Final URL is being proxy passed from another URL. Could this be a probelm?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that. I don't think there is much we can help with without seeing the actual URL you are trying to share.

Comment: Is that the actual URL you are trying to share? Because `http://www.example.com/official-store` returns a 404 of course, and that would explain why the URL is considered “invalid” …